# InvalidCastException while passing Button as parameter C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing a really weird problem I have the following collection :

```
public static readonly IEnumerable<Button> AuraButtons =
        FindObjectsOfType<Button>().Where(button => button.tag == "Aura_Button");
```

and I'm looking for a button with specific name and passing it to a method :

```
UpdateAuraIcon(Settings.AuraButtons.Single(button => button.name == 
        "Aura_Button_" + 1), panel); // 1 is just random number
```

`AuraButtons` does contain the specified button however I get the following exception : `InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.` the method takes a button as parameter but It wont accept it ? That's the method signature

```
private static void UpdateAuraIcon(Button auraButton, GameObject panel)
```

I cant even pass a single integer as parameter :

```
private static void UpdateAuraIcon(int order)
UpdateAuraIcon(1);
```

still throws the same exception.

> Boolean c__AnonStorey3:<>m__B (Button)+0x0 C#
>     Object System.Linq.Enumerable:Single (IEnumerable`1, Func`2, Fallback)+0x22 at :-1
>       Object System.Linq.Enumerable:Single (IEnumerable`1, Func`2)+0xa at :-1 
>       Void Assets.Scripts.Manager:UpdateSelectedAuraPanel (AuraOrder)+0x97    C#
>       Void Assets.Scripts.Manager:SetCurrentAura (GameObject)+0x74    C#
>       Void UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1:Invoke (Object[])+0x3a at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:184    C#
>       Void UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1:Invoke (Object[])+0x7 at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:302   C#
>       Void UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke (Object[])+0x53 at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:630  C#
>       Void UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase:Invoke (Object[])+0xd at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:765  C#
>       Void UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke ()+0x7 at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent_0.cs:53 C#
>       Void Assets.Scripts.Manager:CheckKeys (Dictionary`2, Predicate`1)+0x2d  C#
>       Void Assets.Scripts.Manager:Update ()+0x89  C#

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace and the relevant code? Recommended reading - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Comment: @EugenePodskal added the stacktrace (did i ?)

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in `FindObjectsOfType` and occurs only when the collection is really evaluated ; by using Single (which requires to traverse the whole sequence to ensure that it is really single)

Comment: I tried using foreach to iterate over the collection and when i found a value i just broke out of the loop, stored the result in variable and then pass it to the method still no luck, the same exception is thrown..

Comment: `IEnumerable<Button> a = Settings.AuraButtons.Where(button => button.name == "Aura_Button_" + order);` returns collection of 1 item.

Comment: @Sehnsucht passing `null` as parameter will also throw the exception whaat ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "object" as type for method being called, then cast it to type "Button" inside the method.

```
private static void UpdateAuraIcon(object auraButton, GameObject panel)
{
    Button btn = (Button)auraButton;
...
}
```